# putting an image view in the right corner of button in android

Tags: android

how to put an image in a button at the right corner.that is like, in some applications they putting new tag on the right corner of the Button that is for newly arrived items in the android applications

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adding **android:drawableRight** to your button on XML?

Comment: yes,bro. i tried but the image comes inside button but i want at the right corner of the button.

Comment: <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="@color/blue_color"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Test"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/tag"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white_color"
            android:id="@+id/test"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp" />